# Eclipse: AVD not appearing

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed the ADT bundle for 32 bit. Using Ubuntu 12.04 Updated it a bit and installed the 2.3.3 Android version. I have Eclipse Indigo.

When I use the Android Virtual Machine manager, after choosing a device, I get the progress bar after pressing "Start" but it disappears when it finishes and no virtual machine appears. No errors, too.

I fear it would be a problem with my RAM (Laptop's = 512(or less). Allocated to Device = 128 - 300), having been told by a teacher that the emulator requires 2 GB RAM.

I would like confirmation and/or solution.

Comment: i think RAM is not the problem .... I have 8gb RAM but also having same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can be pretty sure that your RAM capability is the problem (the lack of this one).

When I run Android Studio plus the ADV with an emulator, the memory used by my system is more than 3Gb, and sometimes (ADT + Firefox) it reaches the 3.7Gb.

I use Ubuntu 13.10 64-bits and I've replaced Eclipse for Android Studio, it runs better. You can try with that, but I still think that you'll need to have more RAM to develop Android applications

Comment: Well I'm sad now... I'll wait a bit in case someone else has an idea... But I'll be preparing for a unit change... Thank you, sir.